# how to connect to multiple access databases at one time

Tags: ms-access

Can someone please tell me how I can connect two databases at once? I need to get two sets of data for a conversion we are doing.

`db1` and `db2` are the names. I thought I would do:

```
select * 
from db1.table1 as table1
  inner join db2.table2 as table2 on table2.column = table1.table1.column
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks guys. I was afraid of that. I think I am going to have to do this conversion using a scripting language.

Comment: Whoa, nelly. Setting up a linked table is the way to go for this. Very easy to do, and you can then do a join.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use a scripting language?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the title of the question it sounds like these are Microsoft Access databases, but the question itself doesn't mention if these are Access or another DB.  If these are Access and you have rights to modify them, then this is an option. If not, then this will be of no help whatsoever.

If you're using Microsoft Access, why not create a [linked table](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/products/HA010428201033.aspx) in one of them?  Then you can query both of them in one database...

Comment: It sounds like he's just trying to pull data from these DBs, not modify them.

Answer (score 3):

Access supports this kind of query:

```
SELECT a.d, b.*
  FROM mylocalTable AS a, 
       myLocalTable AS b IN "C:\mydir\mysubdir\myext.mdb" 
 WHERE a.id = b.id;
```

Alternative equivalent syntax:

```
SELECT a.d, b.*
  FROM mylocalTable AS a 
       INNER JOIN 
          [DATABASE=C:\mydir\mysubdir\myext.mdb;].myLocalTable AS b 
          ON a.id = b.id;
```

In the above example, the path to external MDB follows 8.3 file naming style.
Do a dir /x to find the name of the directory and file to see how it will look like.

e.g. c:\program files\mydatabase.mdb might look like c:\progra~1\mydata~1.mdb.

EDIT: Linked table is a better way to deal with this.

Comment: Access supports long file names quite fine in the IN clause in SQL Statements.   So \\servername\Share Name\This is a long file name.MDB is just fine.

Comment: Linked tables aren't necessarily better all the time.   It's more a tradeoff of what works for your situation.

Comment: @Tony: I tried giving in the filename with long path & spaces in the file/directory name and the SQL gave error "ERROR in FROM clause". I am not sure of why it did that.

Comment: @Tony: When is Linked Table not feasible?

Comment: Ahhh, you have to put the long file name in single quotes.   If you are doing a bunch of these programmatically over a period of time you might want to not do the linking and unlinking of tables but just use queries.  If a one time situation then linking would be easier.