# How can I join two tables from two separate databases in MS Access?

Tags: c#, ms-access

How can I join two tables from two separate databases in MS Access? The two MS Access databases have passwords.

Comment: A JOIN is not going to work that way. You can do a query on the first database's table and bring back all its rows (hopefully filtered somehow with a WHERE) and then do a query on the second database's table likewise and then do your JOIN programmatically.

Comment: your recommendation is working very slow so i need two table join from two separate databases.

Comment: Yes I realize that. It's not going to be efficient. Perhaps the answer given by @LeeMac will help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to connect to multiple access databases at one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215373/how-to-connect-to-multiple-access-databases-at-one-time)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to connect to multiple access databases at one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215373/how-to-connect-to-multiple-access-databases-at-one-time)

Answer (score 3):

Import one of the tables as a linked table in the database in which you wish to execute your query.

To link the table, select **Access Database** from the **Import** panel of the **External Data** ribbon tab, and then select the **Link** option from the wizard:

[image]